# c++ 1D wave function bad outputs (finite differences)

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm somewhat new to C and C++ programming, I have already implemented this in R and I am now trying to write it up in C++.

I used `std::vector<double>` and `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` and passed by value because it only needs to pass one row at a time to fill `std::vector<std::vector<double>> u(t.size(),vector<double>(n))` which is sized based on `h`, `k`, and the total run time.

The problem I'm having is that the output data seems to go wrong when the wave crosses the axis. I could not figure out what was wrong with this logically but I could have missed something, I think that it is more likely that I am misusing the `std::vector` or have some data type conflict that I do not recognize.

Perhaps someone else can see what I cannot, here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

vector<double> takestep (double h,double k,vector<double> ukm1,vector<double> ukm2){

   int n = ukm1.size();

   vector<double> uk(n);

   uk[0]=0;
   uk[n-1]=0;

   for(int i = 1; i < (n-1); i++)
   {
       uk[i] = (pow(k,2)/pow(h,2))*(ukm1[i+1]-2*ukm1[i]+ukm1[i-1])+2*ukm1[i]-ukm2[i];
   }

   return uk;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------
vector<vector<double> > solve1D (double tf, double h, double k, vector<double> ukm1, vector<double> ukm2){

  int n = ukm1.size(); 
  vector<double> t((int)tf/k);

  for(int i = 0; i<t.size(); i++)
  {
      t[i] = k*i;
  }

  vector<vector<double> > u(t.size(),vector<double>(n));

  u[0] = ukm1;
  u[1] =  takestep(k,h,ukm1,ukm2); 

  for(int i = 2;i<t.size();i++)
  {
      u[i]= takestep(h,k,u[i-1],u[i-2]);
  }

  return u;
}

//====================================================================
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

 double tf = 12.0;
 double k = .005;
 double h = .01;

 vector<double> x(1.0/h);

 for(int i = 1;i<x.size();i++)
 {
    x[i] = i*h;
 }

 vector<double> yo(x.size()); 

 yo[0]=0;
 yo[x.size()-1]=0;

 for(int i = 1;i<yo.size()-1;i++)
 {
     yo[i] = 0.5*sin(x[i]*M_PI);
 }

 vector<vector<double> > u = solve1D(tf,k,h,yo,yo);

 ofstream myfile;
 myfile.open ("Wave1D_output.txt");


 for(int i = 0;i<u.size();i++)
 {

    for(int j = 0;j<yo.size();j++)
    {
       myfile<< u[i][j]<<"\t";
    }

    myfile<<"\n"; 
 }
 myfile.close();
 return 0;
}
```

---

My R script is fully functional and I'm using mostly the same code (Except with indexes changed). The main difference is the fact that vectors and 2D arrays are (as y'all know) slightly more complicated in C++.

After I finish this I'm going to try and do it using OpenMP, but that's (possibly) another question for another day.

Comment: Please try and add some comments to the code to describe its intended function  and break the equation in function `takestep()` into few simple to understand relations. Finally, try and change your variables names to something meaningful, instead of `i `, `j`, `k` etc. After doing this, if you haven't figured out the problems yourself, we'll be able to help you.

Comment: What's the point of passing yo twice to solve1D? That's an ungainly way to obtain two copies of the same vector, and you don't do anything to either of them. You use ukm1 and ukm2 in the takestep function like it matters, but unless I missed something, it won't. They'll just be copies of the same vector. Also, try using the vector::at operator instead of the raw [] operators - that'll catch you accessing the array out of bounds, just in case. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/

Comment: Two more comments: it doesn't look like you ever get a value for x[0], since you start that loop at 1. Also, constructing a vector with a double is dangerous. Your compiler should throw a warning about that. You intend to construct a vector with size (1.0/.01 = 100), right? If the double representation is very close to 100 but just 99.999999...,it'll DROP the fractional part and leave you with 99. A cheap way to be safe there is to do (1/h + 0.5), but I'd think about how you're doing that.

Comment: I see, I was looking at the first call of takestep. You pass it ukm1 and ukm2, which I believe is just going to be yo and yo at that point. Is that right?

Comment: @mock_blat
Yes, I guess using 4 spaces doesn't work in comments, the truncate and the index on x makes sense though. I'll check it out

Comment: And don't worry @Ziezi, I will definitely add some comments for you, don't think I'll just leave you out in the cold like that. Also I will work on switching from the raw indexing to `vector::at`, because I can tell there is an indexing issue by the fact that my output file has rows where the ends are not zero despite my manually setting them to zero in `takeStep()`.

Comment: @Ziezi, your comments are in the answer, sorry it took so long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out the bug was.............. I sent h and k to the solver backwards in the initial call, I found this out when I printed the size of the times vector and it was 1200 instead of 2400. Ended up keeping the raw indexing since that wasn't the issue. As stated, I added some comments:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include<math.h>
    #include<vector>
    #include<fstream>

    using namespace std;

vector<double> takestep(double h,double k,vector<double> ukm1,vector<double> ukm2){

   int n = ukm1.size();//set n to number of elements in of input array
   vector<double> uk(n);//new array of same size
   uk[0]=0;  //
   uk[n-1]=0;//set ends to zero 

   for(int i = 1;i<(n-1);i++){//for i in length of uk
       uk[i]=(pow(k,2)/pow(h,2))*(ukm1[i+1]-2*ukm1[i]+ukm1[i-1])+2*ukm1[i]-ukm2[i];//finite difference formula
   }

   return uk;//returns next time step
}
vector<vector<double> > solve1D (double tf, double h, double k, vector<double> ukm1, vector<double> ukm2){

  int n = ukm1.size(); //set n to number of elements in input array
  vector<double> t(round(tf/k));//set size of sime sequence (final time/delta time)

  for(int i = 0; i<t.size(); i++){
      t[i] = k*(i+1);                 //fill time array with proper sequence

  }

  vector<vector<double> > u(t.size(),vector<double>(n));//create 2D array to store all the time steps

  u[0] = ukm1;//set initial state
  u[1] =  takestep(k,h,ukm1,ukm2); //set first time step
  for(int i = 2;i<t.size();i++){
      u[i]= takestep(h,k,u[i-1],u[i-2]);//take all the other time steps
  }

  return u;//return array with all steps
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

 double tf = 12.0;//set final time for test
 double k = .005;//set time step
 double h = .01;//set distance for finite difference
 vector<double> x((int)round(1.0/h));//create vector to store x steps
 for(int i = 0;i<x.size();i++){
    x[i] = i*h;                //fill with proper distance steps
 }
 vector<double> yo(x.size());//create vector to store wave function
 for(int i = 1;i<yo.size()-2;i++){
 yo[i] = 0.5*sin(x[i]*M_PI);      //fill with function values
 }
vector<vector<double> > u = solve1D(tf,h,k,yo,yo);//send to solver
```